# Why isn't the hash appended when going to the root of an angular site?

Tags: angularjs, iis

I'm trying to create an angular app using Visual Studio & IIS Express. I'm having an issue with angular routing not working. When I open the site root (`http://localhost:port/`) it just sits there with a blank screen. I know the angular app is initializing because the run-blocks are firing. If I manually add the `#/` at the end, the application works as expected. I don't mind using the `#/` syntax as I'm integrating the site in a legacy application, and I'm afraid html5mode is going to do more harm than good.

How can I have angular auto-suffix itself with the `#/` when I go to the root of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess I'm answering my own question... I was bitten by the "view-inside-include"-"bug". https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1213

Basically, having a `ng-view` inside a file that's `ng-include`-d delays the route initialization. All that was needed to fix the issue was to insert a `$route.reload()` somewhere in the modules `run`-method.

Comment: I got it to work by just injecting `$route` in a run block. I didn't need the `$route.reload()`